# Count number of unique names in Excel with same Ticket #

Tags: excel, count, duplicates, unique

```
Fee     Date    Ticket  Occurence   Name            
1.0     9-Nov   12345   4          SURNAME/NAME         
-1.0    9-Nov   12345   3          SURNAME/NAME         
1.0     9-Nov   12345   2          SURNAME/NAME         
1.0     9-Nov   12345   1          SURNAME/NAME         
1.0     11-Nov  2345    4          SMITH/E          
-1.0    11-Nov  2345    3          SMITH/E          
1.0     11-Nov  2345    2          SMITH/E          
1.0     11-Nov  2345    1          SMITH/E
```

HOW TO COUNT NUMBER OF UNIQUE NAMES WITH SAME TICKET #      and sorted by fee -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 (one -1.0 and three 1.0) ???

Comment: Which version of excel do you use? What is your expected output?

Comment: Can you explain *why* your desired results are 1 and three. I do not see any three unique ticket numbers. Also, please add in your own attempt at solving this problem.

Comment: @JvdV I also need to add filter on fee that only shows -1.0 and 1.0, 1.0, 1.0. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can try below formula if you have `Excel365`.

```
=COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER($E$2:$E$9,$C$2:$C$9=C2)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you but how to sort it by fee -1.0 and 3 entries of 1.0, total 4 entries??

Comment: Couldn't understand. Can you please tell more.

Comment: I need also with the unique ticket number and surname select 4 entries of -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0.